# How to add Prototype JavaScript Framework to jee/jsp/servlet project in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, eclipse, jsp

I have got a jee/jsp/servlet project in Eclipse.
I would like to add this framework (Prototype JavaScript Framework) to my project:

```
https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype#prototype
```

I have added it by using Properties->JavaScript->Include Path... and I have added this file:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js
```

Right now I would like to use this library/framework/code in index.jsp so I have added equivalent path to src in script section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript Resources/Prototype.js">
```

The whole code is below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Card Validator</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript Resources/Prototype.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

I see that it doesn't work could you tell me what is wrong?
Could you also tell me where I can find some code examples how to use it (this Prototype JavaScript Framework)?
I need to write some very basic formula (one textinput and one button) and I am looking for some example...
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a JavaScript file from the web in Eclipse won't include it in your project. You should either download `Prototype.js` and put it on the relative path `/JavaScript Resources/Prototype.js` (I'm not sure if spaces in directory names would be generally a good idea though) or use the original URL to include it in the HTML page, like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but: first of all I think that there shouldn't be '/' at the the end. And the second when I add this src I can run the application, but there is no interaction. Before there was interaction but now there is no.

Comment: @user3455638: the `/` at the end is just shorthand for the `</script>` closing tag. about the no interaction thing... what interaction?